# T-SQL query statement to return records in batches

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Stored procedure returns 1000000 records. How can I modify it by passing parameters to it and return 1-100,101-200,201-300 ( i.e. introduce paging ).

Comment: With a slight modification, you could use the answer I posted to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984768/sql-query-for-asp-net-grid-pagination/10993318#10993318), adding a random ordering on the end.

Comment: Don't follow. You want to return 1-100, then when you return 101-200 you don't care if the order as the same as the first 100? So it could include rows that were already returned in the first 100? If you want to return chunks of rows ("paging") you *need* an `ORDER BY` to be consistent.

Comment: My understanding if there is no explicit "order by" then order of 1000000 is not guaranteed between executions. Unpredictable order  suits me quite well for paging , as long as when paging from the beginning to end , I'll get the same 1000000 rows. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and test the following

Simply pass the pageindex and pagesize
When

```
PageIndex = 1 and PageSize=100 => 1-100
PageIndex = 2 and PageSize=100 => 101-200 and so on


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
(
@PageSize int,
@PageIndex int
)
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
declare 
    @error int,
    @StartRow int,
    @EndRow int

if(@PageIndex < 1)
    Set @PageIndex = 1

Set @StartRow = (@PageSize * (@PageIndex - 1)) + 1
Set @EndRow = @PageSize * @PageIndex

    SELECT * FROM(  
        SELECT
            col1,
            col2,
            col3
        FROM 
    SomeTable s
) s
WHERE ((s.RowNumber Between @StartRow AND @EndRow))
```